# Puppeteer , listen to network response changes

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer api (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)
For automation testing.

I want to listen to all http response, need the url and the response data for each one.

I try to so use the page.on('response') function :

```
 page.on('response', response => {
      response.text().then( textBody=> {
             const req = response.request();;
             console.log(req.url())
             console.log(textBody)
      });
})
```

Should warp in 'waitForSelector' function , to have a flag that the data is ready?

I try to do so.

The problem is some time i do not see any console.log and some time i do.

I will glad to know what do i do wrong?

Comment: The `response` event is [emitted when a response is received](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-response), so you shouldn’t need to wait for anything. Your code looks okay; without any more context, it’s hard to say what the issue might be. When you don’t see the `console.log`, how do you know that the response was received? Try adding a listener for [`requestfailed`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-requestfailed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call [`response.request()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#responserequest), unless you are trying to obtain the URL of the matching request object.

The following solution will work just fine:

```
page.on('response', response => {
  console.log('Response URL:', response.url());

  response.text().then(data => {
    console.log('Response Text:');
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

If you are still having issues, it could be because the associated request has failed.

You can check for this error by listening for the [`requestfailed`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-requestfailed) event and logging the result:

```
page.on('requestfailed', request => {
  console.log('Failed Request URL:', request.url());
  console.log('Failed Request Error Message:', request.failure().errorText);
});
```